# Include in cascade Sequelize

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize with typescript. I have three tables, `WfProjectObject` is joined with `WfProject`, and `WfStep`, joined with `WfProject`.

I want to include `WfStep` with `WfProject` , and not `WfProjectObject`

```
 sequelize.models['WfProjectObject'].findOne({      
    where: {
       objectType: "DOC",
       objectElem: idDoc
    },           
    include: [
       {model: sequelize.models['WfProject'],
       include :[{sequelize.models['WfStep']}] //Here it dosn't work, I have a syntax error 
       },


   ]
})
```

How can I to that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `model` key inside the include.

```
include: [{
                 model: sequelize.models['WfStep']
             }]
```

Answer (score 0):

sequelize.models['WfProjectObject'].findOne({
    where: {

```
   objectType: "DOC",
   objectElem: idDoc

},           
include: [
   {model: sequelize.models['WfProject']},
   {model:[{sequelize.models['WfStep']},
         ]
});
```